# Title attribute value is missing for a social networking icon

Tags: accessibility, title

In a webpage there was a paragraph:Follow Us:Facebook,Twitter.The title was missing for social networking icons.When I inspected the code for the webpage, I saw :the title attribute value was missing:
       
Though the developers say that these icons are clear and self-explanatory,absence of title is not a good accessibility practise.Moreover,as I have highlighted the code is also not as per correct HTML standard.Please suggest what else might be the problem if the title attribute value is missing in the code.

Comment: You should add some code snippet as it's not clear if you're talking about an `img` tag with an `alt` attribute or a CSS background-image on a `div` element with a `title` attribute

Comment: What @Adam said, we need to see a code example. Also, you may want to note the impact of the `title` attribute under different contexts: https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/

Comment: You asked another question that is similar and has code, is it the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822590/missing-tooltip-for-facebook-twitter-icons

Answer (score 2):

There is no accessibility issue for a missing `title` attribute in this context (on an `<a href>`). Do not use it here.

https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/

> Situations in which the the title attribute is not useful due to lack of support:
>
> - Displaying information for web content viewed on mobile phone browsers. Typically in desktop browsers title attribute content is displayed as a tooltip. From what I could find, tooltip display is not supported in any mobile browser and alternative visual methods of accessing title attribute content are not supported.
> - Providing information for people who cannot use a mouse. Typically in desktop browsers, title attribute content is displayed as a tooltip. Although the tooltip behaviour has been supported for 10+ years, no browser (except IE10+ [on focusable elements]) as yet has implemented a practical method to display title attribute content using the keyboard.
> - Using it on most HTML elements to provide information for users of a variety of assistive technologies. Access to title attribute information is not supported uniformly by screen readers

Since the above is copied from my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822590/missing-tooltip-for-facebook-twitter-icons), and this question is not clear what element has the `title`, some more info...

https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2016/02/short-note-on-use-of-alt-and-the-title-attribute/

> - alt="" is a standardised indication to screen reader software that the  is decorative and can be safely ignored. Testing by Powermapper from 2015: IMG with null ALT and non-null TITLE attributes found issues with alt="" + non-empty title.
> - Absence of an alt attribute results, in some screen reading screen reader software, not conveying the  to users.
>
>   - Note: Found this issue with JAWS 17 and Chrome 48 on Windows 10. Testing by Powermapper from 2015: IMG with TITLE Screen reader compatibility found no issues with this pattern.
> - Some browsers implement the HTML5 requirement that alt="" is equal to role="presentation" which results in the  being removed from the accessibility tree, so despite there being a non empty title, the  is hidden.