# Missing Tooltip for Facebook/Twitter icons

Tags: tooltip, accessibility

In a webpage,there was no tooltip present for Facebook/Twitter icons.When I inspected the code for the webpage, I saw :the **title attribute value** was missing as highlighted in the code below.

```
    <a onclick="ga('send', 'social', 'Facebook', 
    'send''https://www.Website');"
    href="https://www.Website" **title** target="_blank" ><img 
    src="http://www.Website/themes/act/images/facebook-mouseover.jpg" 
    alt="Facebook" ></a>
```

Please suggest the accessibility issue that might occur if "title" has no value in the HTML code.

Comment: Is this question just a variation of your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816880/title-attribute-value-is-missing-for-a-social-networking-icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Title attribute value is missing for a social networking icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816880/title-attribute-value-is-missing-for-a-social-networking-icon)

Answer (score 0):

There is no accessibility issue for a missing `title` attribute in this context (on an `<a href>`). Do not use it here.

https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/

> Situations in which the the title attribute is not useful due to lack of support:
>
> - Displaying information for web content viewed on mobile phone browsers. Typically in desktop browsers title attribute content is displayed as a tooltip. From what I could find, tooltip display is not supported in any mobile browser and alternative visual methods of accessing title attribute content are not supported.
> - Providing information for people who cannot use a mouse. Typically in desktop browsers, title attribute content is displayed as a tooltip. Although the tooltip behaviour has been supported for 10+ years, no browser (except IE10+ [on focusable elements]) as yet has implemented a practical method to display title attribute content using the keyboard.
> - Using it on most HTML elements to provide information for users of a variety of assistive technologies. Access to title attribute information is not supported uniformly by screen readers

Comment: "Do not use it here": Why’s that? You shouldn’t *rely* on the `title`, but adding it shouldn’t be harmful, right? It can help in some situations (i.e,, sometimes, for some users). In OP’s case, if no other kind of visible label is provided, it would be better than nothing.

Comment: Some users of zooming tools get stymied by tool-tips. Too often tool-tips are seen as adequate by developers, meaning they do not bother to make the item itself more understandable. Tool-tips sometimes are not matched to the item or do not match associated alt text, and in [some cases](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2016/02/short-note-on-use-of-alt-and-the-title-attribute/) can mess with the accessible name calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Although the image has an `alt` attribute, this code has an explicit empty `title` tag which can lead to undetermined behavior from screenreaders.

You have two solutions:

- You can remove the empty `title` attribute from the `a` tag.
- You can use this `title` attribute to show an information that may be facultatively seen by people using screenreaders (as the `title` attribute does not have a good screenreader support)

If you want to explicitely target people using a screen reader use, the `aria-label` attribute on the `a` element. For instance:

```
<a href="https://www.Website" target="_blank" 
  title="Publish to Facebook (⧉)"
  aria-label="Publish to Facebook (opens in a new tab)">
   <img src="http://www.Website/themes/act/images/facebook-mouseover.jpg" 
  alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```